# How can this C ++ loop code be in Kotlin?

Tags: c++, loops, kotlin

I had such a problem working on the codeforces site at kotlin.
How can this code in C ++ be in Kotlin?

```
for (int pw = 1; pw <= n; pw = pw * 10 + 1) {
    for (int d = 1; d <= 9;  d++) {
      if (pw * d <= n) {
        //code
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Would "Could you transpile this code for me?" be a synonim for this question? I didnt downvote but this is off-topic

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html

Comment: @RetiredNinja honestly given the shape of these loops, the answer is not quite obvious from the docs. The kotlin default ranges don't support multiplication like this for changing the loop variables.

Comment: @SomerandomITboy you can see it this way, or maybe the OP is just asking about how to achieve similar complex loops in Kotlin, which is not necessarily obvious (admittedly the question could be formulated differently of course)

Answer (score 1):

Basic [Kotlin ranges and progressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ranges.html), and thus Kotlin `for` loops cannot express the outer loop the same way. You should either resort to [a `while` loop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#while-loops) or use something like `generateSequence`.

Using a `while` loop:

```kotlin
var pw = 1
while (pw <= n) {
    for (d in 1..9) {
        if (pw * d <= n) {
            //code
        }
    }
    pw = pw * 10 + 1
}
```